# PHP loop through checkbox array to show values

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

How do I loop through a checkbox array so it shows each value?

Original code:

```
  <form class="form" method="POST" action="index.php?id=22">
<? if (!$_POST['step']) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />
        <tr>
      <td width="300" valign="top"><label style="margin-right: 25px;">
          <input style="width: 25px;" type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="Pharmaceuticals" id="member3_pharma" />Pharmaceuticals</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="300" valign="top"><label style="margin-right: 25px;">
          <input style="width: 25px;" type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="Medical Devices" id="member3_devices" />
          Medical Devices</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="300" valign="top"><label style="margin-right: 25px;">
          <input style="width: 25px;" type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="Legal" id="member3_legal" />
          Legal</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <button class="blue medium awesome awesomeforward" style="margin: 10px; float: right;" type="submit" name="submit">Next step</button>
<? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 3) {

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if ($name <> "step") { echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" />"; }
}

?>
        <tr>
      <td><label for="member4_total">Total no. employees (Welsh Site)</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="member4_total" id="member4_total" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="member4_turnover">Turnover (from Welsh site)</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="member4_turnover" id="member4_turnover" /></td>
    </tr>
    <? } else if ($_POST['step'] == 4) { //do posting and send email here! 

$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "MediWales member application";

$CheckboxGroup2_field = $_POST['CheckboxGroup2'];

$body = "$CheckboxGroup2_field";


mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "Thank you for your account application, we will contact you shortly.";

} ?>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
$checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want to comma-separate them, you could also use implode(', ', $_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1']). You wouldn't even need to use the foreach().

Answer (score 4):

put `name="CheckboxGroup2[]"`

and get the data in array form

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I've got a multi step form that's doing this at the top aswell - <? if (!$_POST['step']) { ?>

Comment: @Rob: Maybe you're thinking about it too hard because it's really that simple. Rename 'CheckboxGroup2' to 'CheckboxGroup2[]', and that should be it. PHP automatically turns such variables into arrays. - after that you just need to know how to loop through an array. :)

Comment: Which I don't know how to do :/

Comment: Ok, I'm getting somewhere now, it's just saying array in the email so just need to know how to loop through the checkboxes.

Comment: $_POST['CheckboxGroup2'] holds the array. So do this: `foreach($_POST['CheckboxGroup2'] as $key=>$value) {echo $key."= ".$value."<br/>";}` this will output the values of all the checked checkboxes

Comment: Thanks Jules, that looks as though it's along the right lines. Which part do I put that in though, this line - $CheckboxGroup2_field = $_POST['CheckboxGroup2']; or this line - $body = "$CheckboxGroup2_field";. The second line throws up errors from the code though.

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of @diEcho's post, your form should look like

```
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup1[]' value='1'> One
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup1[]' value='2'> Two
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup1[]' value='3'> Three
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup1[]' value='4'> Four

<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup2[]' value='1'> One
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup2[]' value='2'> Two
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup2[]' value='3'> Three
<input type='checkbox' name='CBgroup2[]' value='4'> Four
```

On the backend, the `$_POST['CBgroup1']` field will be an array instead of a single value. You'll want to loop through that array to see which ones are checked.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see from the comments on the other answer, I don't know how to loop through the array to show the results. I kinda need some hand holding on this!

Comment: @Rob - You want to use `foreach($_POST['CBgroup1'] as $key=>$value)`. Every value which was checked will be in the array, and those that weren't checked won't be present. Play around with it and you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(isset($_POST['CBgroup1']))
#to ensure that $_POST[yadda] exists, otherwise you get a happy error
    if(in_array("4",$_POST['CBgroup1']))
    #searches your array for "4", if you like this make sure each value checkbox is unique
         echo "The fourth checkbox is checked.";
```

I wanted this in reply to eykanal, but I don't think I have enough reputation. (Please tell me if I missed something obvious, this is my first post ever =)